# Display just the bottom left quarter inside img tag on prepend

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to prepend an `<img>` tag to a `<div>` like [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Dana15/2mLbhmuL/9/) but I need to display just the bottom left quarter of it, not just the full one.

**Markup**

```
<div id="myDiv"></div>
```

**Javascript**

```
imgUrl = "nerdist.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/02/oblivion-song-615x346.png"
$('#myDiv').prepend('<img id="theImg" style="width:100%;" src="https://' + imgUrl + '"/>');
```

It is possible to display just a part of the image from the image src?

Comment: why are you setting the image as a background and not as a `src`?

Comment: You want to **append** yet you are **prepend**ing... just FYI

Comment: Try to inspect you image in Developer Tools in your browser. Make sure that it can be loaded with that url.

Comment: @fcalderan I'm a beginner in HTML coding so after trying to use src and not be able to display just a quarter of it I've tried using background. I'm trying to learn from mistakes

Comment: it's fine to learn from mistakes but you should ask about the *actual problem* rather than the *attempted solution*. if you have a positioning issue provide a minimum verifiable code example and edit your original question.

Comment: @fcalderan I've updated my question. Thanks for your support :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve what you are trying to do, you need to style your code to adjust the image, showing only the quarter that you want by positioning the `img` as `relative` and utilizing `top and left` decalartions. to show a quarter (25%), we will hide (75%) in both direction.

I included a live sample for you.
check out the css, understand the mathematics and modify as much as you want. note that you must give `height` to the img-wrapper. without it, the `top` and `left` properties wont work.

Meanwhile, in the your js code, an image cannot have a background image, rather use the `src` attribute to specify the image location. I hope this solves your problem

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    //create the image here
    var img = document.createElement('img');
    
    //listen for load event on the image.
    img.addEventListener('load', function(e) {
        var height = this.offsetHeight,
        width = this.offsetWidth;
        
        var hiddenheight = parseInt(0.75 * height),
        visibleheight = parseInt(0.25 * height),
        hiddenwidth = parseInt(0.75 * width);
        
        $(this).css({
            'top': '-' + hiddenheight + 'px',
            'right': '-' + hiddenwidth + 'px'
        });
        
        $('.img-wrapper').css({
            'max-height': visibleheight + 'px'
        });
    });
    $('.img-wrapper').append(img);
    $(img).attr({
       'src': 'http://fjsfoundations.com/image/global/tile.jpg',
       'alt': 'test image'
    });
});
```

```css
.img-wrapper {
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: blue;
    position: relative;
}

.img-wrapper > img {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
    <div class="img-wrapper"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: It's there a way to remove the blue background and make the quarter the same size as the div?

Comment: sure there is. you will have to calculate the height of the image using javascript, then get 25% of that height, and set it on the div.

Comment: i have edited the code to use majorly javascript to do the required calculations. please use the code with care. i am glad to provide more assistance if need be. I think i have tried for you. lol.

Comment: Thanks a lot for you answer! Happy coding! :)

Answer (score 1):

You do not add background to a `img`. Either add background to `div` or add an  `<img src=""`

```
$('#myDiv').prepend('<img id="theImg" src="https://' + imgUrl + '"/>');
```

This will `prepend` the `img` tag, to append it (attach it to the last) then use `.append()`

You might need to style this image for proper alignment which you can do using

```
#theImg{
   /* Your CSS here */
}
```

Comment: My first attempt was with src but I did't know how to align it proper in order to display just the bottom left quarter and after some researches I've tried to use background but I couldn't see the image

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("#mydiv").html("<img id="theImg" src="............" />");
```

and you can either have the img tag have it's css preset or you can do it in javascript using the same methord but using

```
$("#mydiv").css(...........................);
```

if this is the way you'd like it then i'll help more.